# How to display image using javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript code and i want to insert an image inside the dynamically created html page. Please correct me if i'm going wrong with the code. the code runs something like this:

```js
var html = [
  '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container");">',
  '<img src=' + image1 + '>',
  '</div>'
].join('\n');

_dockPanel.container.append(html);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine, assuming all the variables reference valid elements. Is there an issue with the code?

Comment: What is the image src? Your variable for the image is undeclared.

Comment: I'm declaring the image path with the variable(var image1="image_path") @gwalshington

Comment: I'm not able to display the image inside the html. should we give an absolute path or a relative path, if so how should we actually code for that.@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Okay - think you should look at your src path. Try replacing that with `var image1="http://r.ddmcdn.com/w_606/s_f/o_1/cx_0/cy_15/cw_606/ch_404/APL/uploads/2014/06/10-kitten-cuteness-1.jpg"` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here: `...container");">'`

Here is the working (for demo purpose slightly modified) fiddle:

```js
var image1 = 'https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg';
var html = [
  '<div class="uicomponent-panel-controls-container">',
  '<img src=' + image1 + '>',
  '</div>'
].join('\n');

document.getElementById("dock").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="dock"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = [...].join('');
```

html rendering dom does not need to be separated by '\n'